# Distorted graphics, problems with starting up

Tags: graphics, desktop-background

Using the newest version of Ubuntu, freshly installed. NVIDIA GeForce GTX 560 Ti. It's mostly the font that doesn't render well, I think. Small logos do it too, sometimes.

Screenshot to clarify (see bookmarks, search bar, etc.)
[image]

Another screenshot
[image: EDIT: [Another screenshot.](http://i.imgur.com/O287i.png)]

And, sometimes when I start up, I get only a black screen saying [OK]. I can move my mouse around, but nothing helps, except for restarting.

Also, my desktop picture doesn't stay the same. Every time I start up Ubuntu it goes back to the standard purple background.

They're not very serious problems, but it's all a little annoying. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED:

I went [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia), and used the Installation from the console-thing. I put "jockey-text -e kmod:nvidia_current" in the terminal (because xorg:nvidia_current didn't work). It asked for my password and did absolutely nothing after that. So I rebooted. And it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem with my NVIDIA GeFroce GTS 450. I went to additional drivers and changed to the proprietary driver from NVIDIA and rebooted.